# How do I get Path Auto to display one value in the URL structure when node:field has multiple values?

Tags: 7, tokens, path-aliases

Using path auto to create a url structure, I would like the following:

my-content-type/[node:field_restaurant_category]

Note that node:field_restaurant_category can have multiple values, and in my url structure this is unfortunately the case. I have a url now that is my-content-type/t1-t2-t3-t4-tetc

How can I limited the node:field_restaurant_category to be just one and only one term? I honestly don't care which term the module chooses so long as the limitation is in place.

I read earlier that something like node:field_restaurant_category:values:1 should work, or something, but I cannot get any logical configuration of that to work correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For multiple cardinality fields you can use a pattern like `[node:field-name:1]` (note the use of hyphens instead of underscores).

This is an example of the tokens available for a field called `field_profile_categories` with multiple values:

[image]

I think in your case the pattern should be:

```
[node:field-restaurant-category:1]
```

Although the comments in the token table suggest that deltas start at `0`, so you might need to use `[node:field-restaurant-category:0]` if you want the first item to be used.

Comment: Indeed, they do need to start at 0, else, fields with just one term do not work. Otherwise, solution works great! Thanks!